# Do repulsor craft have a height limit?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, technology, vehicles

Repulsor-craft are land-based (usually) vehicles designed to levitate above the surface during operational use.

Is there a technical limit to the achievable height? Most seem to hover just slightly above the surface, but Separatist STAPs have been seen on Teth being used like an airborne infantry vehicle high above the surface.

Answer (score 6):

### Repulsorlift technology has no height limit except the one imposed by the gravity well

> **STAP**
>
> STAPs are lightweight reconnaissance and patrol vehicles used by the battle droids of the Trade Federation army (and later, the Separatist Alliance). ***Incorporating repulsorlift technology***, the STAP (single trooper aerial platform) is a slim, agile craft sporting a pair of blaster cannons. STAPs are often deployed as support vehicles in conjunction with larger craft.
>
> *Encyclopedia (StarWars.com)*

That was your example of a craft levitated to great heights with repulsorlift but there are other, much heavier vehicles, with that technology:

- [Patrol Transport](http://www.starwars.com/databank/patrol-transport)
- [Bespin Cloud-Car](http://www.starwars.com/databank/cloud-car)
- [Core Ships](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Core_ship/Legends)
- [Bespin it-self](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud_City)

So it seems there is no limit to the achievable height with an amount of repulsor engines large enough... except possibly one: the size of the gravity well. Repulsor technology seems to work [pushing against a gravity](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Repulsorlift) so it doesn't work that well as gravity comes close to 0. Yet Core Ships can escape orbit in planets the likes of [Geonosys](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Core_ship/Legends) and we don't know any example of a height limit in a smaller planet.

Edit:
As pointed in the comments the list of ships with repulsor technology is larger and respulsors can be powerful enough to even be weaponized with large destruction as a result.

Comment: Just to add, there are other, even heavier things that seem to be able to enter atmosphere and hover using repulsors - Core Ships for Lucrehulk Battleships use repulsors almost constantly and then actually take off. We saw an Imp-Class SD hover over Jedha in Rogue One, Acclamators regularly land and take off.

Comment: @WraithLeader And in Legends, you have a repulsor powerful enough to destroy stars.

Comment: @JAB what was that one called? I remember sun crusher but that used resonance torpedos

Comment: @WraithLeader Centerpoint Station.

Comment: @JAB The planets of the Corellian system where the ones with repulsors on their surface capable of destroying the Centerpoint Station. The Station used a not well understood technology based on tractor beams

Comment: @Ram The Station used the same system as on the planets, just larger (and with a hyperspace component). That was the reason for the discussion about modern repulsors being made of a bunch of little tiny cones and then the realization about the giant "mountains" in the station.

Comment: Just realized I should have clarified: The repulsor discussion was given in the Corellian Trilogy, which I believe was the first mention of Centerpoint Station's usage as a weapon. It's possible that they've since retconned the description given there, however. I haven't kept up with Legends stuff in years.