# Could cloud cars be flown in space?

Tags: star-wars

Although it says that [cloud cars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud_car) are atmospheric vehicles, can they be flown in space, even as a poor performing space fighter. This might echo of the [TIE striker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE/sk_x1_experimental_air_superiority_fighter) as it was a poor star fighter, but it was also a good atmospheric fighter. 

So can cloud cars be flown in space?

Comment: related https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163678/do-repulsor-craft-have-a-height-limit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're described in their [official Databank article](http://www.starwars.com/databank/cloud-car) as *atmospheric* craft.

> *These brick-colored **atmospheric** vehicles keep the peace in the skies
>   of Bespin. Cloud cars feature twin “pods” connected by a repulsorlift
>   engine*

There's no mention of their capacity to go into outer space.

---

The Star Wars: Official Fact File [article on Cloud Cars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_32) is even more explicit. These craft are intended for in-atmosphere use only. They lack the basic capacity for the occupants to survive in free space for any longer than their air will last, let alone maneuver once they get there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*brick-colored atmospheric vehicles keep the peace in the skies of Bespin*" - for some reason, I read this as Britain. What HAVE the Met been up to now?

Comment: Rendered in a mid Atlantic accent, in black and white.